Pip install failed for package: -r while Running dataflow Flex template with providing Requirements.txt NewConnectionError
Getting following errors after launching dataflow template - code execution starts and once pipeline graph generation starts, getting this 
"subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', '/tmp/tmpomr2b4n9/tmp_requirements.txt', '--exists-action', 'i', '--no-deps', '--implementation', 'cp', '--abi', 'cp38', '--platform', 'manylinux2014_x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1."}



Pip install failed for package: -r           "}
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2024/05/29 14:53:10.869696","line":"exec.go:66","message":" Output from execution of subprocess: b\"WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5f4c7bde50\u003e: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/google-cloud-storage/}
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2024/05/29 14:53:11.262883","line":"exec.go:52","message":"python failed with exit status 1"}
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2024/05/29 14:53:11.263007","line":"launch.go:80","message":"Error: Template launch failed: exit status 1"}


Following is my requirements.txt

apache-beam[gcp]
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-logging
pandas
pandas-gbq
db-dtypes

Following is my metadata.json
{
    "name": "Getting started Batch Pipeline",
    "description": "Batch Pipeline flex template for Python.",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "output",
        "label": "Output destination",
        "helpText": "The path and filename prefix for writing output files. Example: gs://your-bucket/your-path",
        "regexes": [
          "^gs:\\/\\/[^\\n\\r]+$"
        ]
      }
    ]
}


This is dummy batch_pipeline.py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.textio import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


def write_to_cloud_storage(argv=None):
    # Parse the pipeline options passed into the application.
    class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
        @classmethod
        # Define a custom pipeline option that specfies the Cloud Storage bucket.
        def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
            parser.add_argument("--output", required=True)

    wordsList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    options = MyOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Create elements" >> beam.Create(wordsList)
            | "Write Files" >> WriteToText(options.output, file_name_suffix=".txt")
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_to_cloud_storage()

Using following command I am building the flex template
   gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/batch_pipeline-req-py.json 
   --image-gcr-path "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<BUCKET_NAME>/batch-pipeline-python:V1"    \
   --sdk-language "PYTHON"  \
   --flex-template-base-image "PYTHON3"  \
   --metadata-file "metadata.json"  \
   --py-path "."  \
   --env "FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=batch_pipeline.py"  \
   --env "FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE=requirements.txt"

   - Following command is used to run the template on DataflowRunner

   gcloud dataflow flex-template run "batch-pipeline-flex" 
   --template-file-gcs-location "gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/batch_pipeline-req-py.json" \
   --service-account-email "service-dfl-ingest@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
   --subnetwork "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/<SUBNETWORK>"    \
   --parameters output="gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/output-" \
   --region "europe-west1" 

   >! Service account has following IAM roles





Hi @ShubhGurukul, Could you please follow the troubleshooting steps mentioned in this documentation and let me know if your issue is resolved or not.

Can your Dataflow worker can access the internet? Looks like it tries to call pip to install the depended packages.

yes, the Dataflow worker has access to the internet.
